# How to remove rows with NAs from two dataframes based on NAs from one?

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I am trying to remove the same rows with `NA` in df1 from df2.
eg.

```
df1
    A
1   1
2   NA
3   7
4   NA


df2
    A B C D
1   2 4 7 10
2   3 6 1 3
3   9 5 1 3
4   4 9 2 5
```

Intended outcome:

```
df1
    A
1   1
3   7


df2
    A B C D
1   2 4 7 10
3   9 5 1 3
```

I have already tried things along the lines of...

```
newdf <- df2[-which(rowSums(is.na(df1))),]
```

and

```
noNA <- function(x) { x[!rowSums(!is.na(df1)) == 1]}
NMR_6mos_noNA <- as.data.frame(lapply(df2, noNA))
```

or

```
noNA <- function(x) { x[,!is.na(df1)]}
newdf3 <- as.data.frame(lapply(df2, noNA))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `is.na` to create a logical condition and use that to subset the rows of 'df1' and 'df2'

```
i1 <- !is.na(df1$A)
df1[i1, , drop = FALSE]
#  A
#1 1
#3 7

df2[i1,]
#   A B C  D
# 1 2 4 7 10
#3 9 5 1  3
```